# Determine the size of a hashed varchar column

Tags: sql-server, hashing

I am using SQL Server.

I have this table:

```
create table MyTable (
ID int not null ,
Name varchar(500) )
```

and I am adding a `name_hash` column to store hash values for the `name` column:

```
alter myTable
    add 
    name_hash AS HASHBYTES('SHA1', CONVERT(VARCHAR(90), Name))
```

How can I determine the resulting size of `name_hash`? Is it related to the size of the column that I want to apply the hashing to?

Comment: This answer should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722305/what-kind-of-datatype-should-one-use-to-store-hashes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well - it appears that a fellow Stack Exchange member (Richard Marskell - Drackir)  has figured this out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16680423).

I've copied his answer below:

> You should use the binary datatype. You can use binary instead of
>   varbinary because the hash function will always return the same number
>   of bytes for the same type of hash (e.g. MD5, SHA1, etc.). This will
>   cut down on the (slight) overhead required to manage a variable length
>   binary (varbinary) column.
>
> In terms of what size to make it, you can run this query to check the
>   length of each hash type:

```
SELECT  DATALENGTH(HASHBYTES('MD2', 'Testing')) AS [MD2Length],
        DATALENGTH(HASHBYTES('MD4', 'Testing')) AS [MD4Length],
        DATALENGTH(HASHBYTES('MD5', 'Testing')) AS [MD5Length],
        DATALENGTH(HASHBYTES('SHA', 'Testing')) AS [SHALength],
        DATALENGTH(HASHBYTES('SHA1', 'Testing')) AS [SHA1Length],
        /* 2012 only: */
        DATALENGTH(HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', 'Testing')) AS [SHA2_256Length],
        DATALENGTH(HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', 'Testing')) AS [SHA2_512Length];
```

And it should come out with this:

```
MD2Length MD4Length MD5Length SHALength SHA1Length SHA2_256Length SHA2_512Length
--------- --------- --------- --------- ---------- -------------- --------------
16        16        16        20        20         32             64
```